# Retrieve Command bar actions for entity metadata

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm trying to retrieve a list of actions that can be performed over a given entity (says an opportunity) from CRM
I'm not sure if that exists, and so far I haven't found anything by googling that. I guess (and really hope) that those action shortcuts are related to the Entity Metadata, and with the corresponding statecode / statuscode for a given entity.

Let's show a bit more:
As you can see in the web client, the Opportunity entity offers different actions at the ribbon, based in it statecode. In the image below, you can see that open opportunities offer actions (shortcuts) for "Close as Won", and "Close as Lost"

[image]

When the opportunity is closed, the ribbon offer only Reopen action.

[image]

These actions has other behaviors related (ie. when you close an opportunity, a new entity named OpportunityClose is created with other fields), but I don't pretend to go in those details.

**So far I only want to know if these actions can be retrieved in some way, in the Entity Metadata. Something like ActionsMetadta where you can see the actions name, the state code when should be offered, etc.**

TIA!
Milton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can retrieve only the actions, but whole ribbon definitions are available in SDK (`SDK\Resources\ExportedRibbonXml` folder). You can have a look and try pick information you need.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334699.aspx) you can find more info how to get ribbons programmatically.